# Rvm, please tell me if I understood this correctly!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

So with RVM, you can run different versions Ruby i.e. 1.8.7 or 1.9.2

Within each ruby version, you can create as many gemsets as you want.

What does the '@' symbol represent in the name? does it do anything special?

i've seen people use:

rvm gemset create xxxx@rails3  or xxxx@rails2.1.1

that is just a naming convention correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is just a symbol to separate the Ruby version and the gemset.

you can also use

```
rvm 1.9.2
rvm gemset use rails238
```

which is the same as

```
rvm 1.9.2@rails238
```

the command

```
rvm list gemsets
```

will tell you the Ruby and gemset you are using

Comment: oh so its a shortcut to load a particular ruby version + gemset gothca thnks!